# php if AND mysql empty

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, null

```
Database: Links

Table: Company (id INT, name VARCHAR)
Table: Employee (id INT, name VARCHAR, company_id INT)
Table: Links (id INT, name VARCHAR, employee_id)
```

The above eventually displays a list of links that a certain person from a certain company can click on.

I am trying to develop an update user page.

So far I have got drop downs for company and employee and tickboxes to highlight what the user can see.

I can parse these through a form quite happily.  My question is:

**How do I convert the following into a single line that I can replicate for the other 11 checkboxes?**

```
if ($_POST[Protection]=1 AND *SEE BELOW*=0)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO links (ID, name, employee_id) VALUES ('', 'Protection', '$_POST[emp_id]')";
}

if ($_POST[Protection]=0 AND *SEE BELOW*=1)
{
//DROP From links
}


*FROM ABOVE*
$query= 'SELECT * FROM links'." WHERE id=$POST[id] AND name=Protection"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query " . mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array of the available checkboxes and iterate over them in a loop:

```
$checkboxes = array('Protection', 'AnotherOption', 'YetAnotherOption');

foreach ($checkboxes AS $key => $value)
{
    if (!isset($_POST[$value]) continue;

    if ($_POST[$value] == 1)
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO links (ID, name, employee_id) VALUES ('', '$value', '{$_POST['emp_id']}')");

    elseif ($_POST[$value] == 0)
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM links WHERE employee_id='{$_POST['emp_id']}' AND name='$value'");
}
```

OR

```
foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value)
{
    if (in_array($key, $checkboxes))
    {
        if ($value == 1)
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO links (ID, name, employee_id) VALUES ('', '$key', '{$_POST['emp_id']}')");

        elseif ($value == 0)
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM links WHERE employee_id='{$_POST['emp_id']}' AND name='$key'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting, will try tomorrow in the office.  Getting my head around the code, where does the name of the checkbox get added into the database? I understand the value=1(ticked) and =0(unticked), but cant see how it populates the name of the checkbox into the db.

Comment: In the second example, the name of the checkbox is held in the variable $key. In the first example, it's in $value